# Function within function to change a variable value

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Why doesn't the variable url change?

```
def test():
    url = "Start"

    def change():
        global url
        url = "End"

    change()
    print(url)

    return url
```

test()

And yes, it needs to be a function within a function. That way the rest of my code is more simple.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Another approach to this is to put `url` in a mutable container, e.g. a list -- `url = ["Start"]`; `url[0] = "End"`; `return url[0]`.  No `global`/`nonlocal` needed that way.

Comment: @Samwise I'd prefer a dataclass with unfrozen values.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables are those defined at the top-level scope of a module, not just any variable defined outside the scope of a function. The variable defined in `test` is a *nonlocal* variable from `change`'s perspective, not a global variable.

Use the `nonlocal` keyword instead:

```
def test():
    url = "Start"

    def change():
        nonlocal url
        url = "End"

    change()
    print(url)

    return url
```

`nonlocal` causes the assignment to take place in the closest enclosing scope where `url` is defined. (If no such *local* scope
exists, the `nonlocal` declaration is a syntax error. A definition in the global scope does not count, in contrast with free variables who are looked up in the closest enclosing scope, whether local or global.)

---

In your original function, `change` really does set (or even create) a global variable named `url`. For example:

```
def test():
    url = "Start"

    def change():
        global url
        url = "End"

    change()
    print(url)

    return url

try:
    print(url)
except NameError:
    print("'url' not yet defined")

test()  # Outputs "Start"
print(url)  # Outputs "End"
```

Comment: Thank you! I have coded in python for a year now and I had never heard of that keyword before xd

Comment: It's relatively new, having been introduced in Python 3. If you are coming from a Python 2 background, you may not realize it exists, and even if you started in Python 3, you may not necessarily recognize when a use-case for it exists.

Comment: The assignment creates the variable, not the `nonlocal` declaration itself.

Comment: Hm. That does seem to be the case if *no* non-local variable exists (even if a true global does as well). I had a more complicated example with more levels of nesting, where it seemed to create a new local variable in the immediate local scope without affecting a pre-existing `url` higher in the stack. And of course I've already deleted the file. Let me see if I can recreate it to figure what I actually did.

Comment: OK, I misinterpreted a regular free-variable lookup in the closest enclosing scope with the creation of a new local variable.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the `nonlocal` keyword

```
def test():
    url = "Start"
    def change():
        nonlocal url
        url = "End"

    change()
    print(url)

    return url
```